# Meaning of these characters

Tags: character-identification

Hello I wanted to ask if someone knows the meaning of These characters:

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Chinese_Wikipedia

Comment: @songyuanyao So this means `Chinese Wikipedia` ?

Comment: You want to know the literal meaning? `维基` is `wikipedia`, `大典` means `重要的典籍` here, i.e. `collection of great classics`.

Comment: Translating 'Wikipedia' to Chinese, but in ancient Chinese style, just like 永樂大典, an encyclopedia compiled at 永乐 (an emperor of Qing dynasty) era.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

维基大典, as the comments shown, means Wikipedia

> There are two ways for translation in Chinese.
>
> 1. By their pronunciation
> 2. By their function

In the first part "Wiki" is translation by its pronunciation. Thus,

```
"Wi" sound could be written as 维
"Ki" sound could be written as 基
```

While in the second part, "大典" is translated by its function.

Suffix "-pedia" is from the greek root paideia, meaning education, culture. And in English "-pedia" is for something that have a knowledgeable collection for something.

```
"大典" in Chinese equals to Encyclopedia. 

"典" in Chinese means a collection of influential and important works
```

So if you have a Chinese dictionary, you will find it is called

```
eg.「字典」means word dictionary
```

ie. a collection of words with elaborations and meanings, and it is important for language learners.

It is also that's why "Wiki-pedia" could just get the name "Wiki" and "-pedia" is not directly translated by pronunciation as "大典" could already explain it.

Answer (score 0):

维基大典 is a name of Wikipedia - Classical Chinese version.So it's The Encyclopedia writen in Classical Chinese.

Literal meaning, Great Collection in Wikipedia.